# Slick 'autoplay' does not starts automatically

Tags: javascript

So I have site and I'm using Slick.js in the gallery to show images, I also use Angularjs. The problem is that 'autoplay' does not triggered when this function called when the controller loaded to the site.

```
// Set up slick carousel.
function setCarousel() {
    console.log( "carousel started" );
    $('.single-item').slick( {,
        autoplay: true,
        slide: 'div',
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        dots : true
    });
};
```

So the function is called whenever the user selects the gallery site where the controller is:

```
   myApp.controller( 'pageController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http ) {

        setCarousel();
    } ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma after the `{` character. So it should look like this :

```
 $('.single-item').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      slide: 'div',
      autoplaySpeed: 2000,
      dots : true
 });
```

Comment: ok,  Are you getting "carousel started" on the console and no errors printing there? Also can you try adding this as one of the settings `infinite: true`

Comment: Well the Slick works perfectly I can slide between the images and yes the console says 'carousel started'. It is only the autostart option which is not working even the dots are visible which come from the options beacuse their default is false.